# Symbols accross the top

Tags: pandas, seaborn, heatmap, correlation

I would like the symbols accross the top, not the bottom. Can't find docs on how to do this?

```
fig, x = plt.subplots(figsize=(width, height))
x = seaborn.heatmap(corr_df, annot=True, cmap='RdYlGn')
st.pyplot(fig)
```

Comment: `sns.heatmap` is a `matplotlib.Axes` level plot, as such, `matplotlib` formatting methods apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you are looking for [`xaxis.tick_top`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.XAxis.tick_top.html):

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

glue = sns.load_dataset("glue").pivot("Model", "Task", "Score")
ax = sns.heatmap(glue)
ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.xaxis.tick_top()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]